# Como puedo insertar datos a un Chart.js con ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, base-de-datos, chart.js

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Cocina", "Limpieza", "Atención", "Parqueo", "Local"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '',
        data: [100, 92, 80, 96, 75],
        backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 5)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 5)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 5)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 5)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 5)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 5)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {

      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
{ "EvaluationDetails" : [ { "aspectId" : 0 , "aspectResult" : 0 } ] , "evaluationTemplateId" : 0 , "entityId" : 0 , "número" : 0 }
```

Comment: cuales son los datos que quieres meter? por un ejemplo de los datos recibidos! ya que los que veo son puros 0;

Comment: {
    "evaluationDetails": [
        {
            "aspectId": 1,
            "aspectResult": 100
        },
        {
            "aspectId": 2,
            "aspectResult": 90
        },
        {
            "aspectId": 3,
            "aspectResult": 10
        },
        {
            "aspectId": 4,
            "aspectResult": 50
        },
        {
            "aspectId": 5,
            "aspectResult": 40
        }
    ],
    "evaluationTemplateId": 1,
    "entityId": 1,
    "result": 58
}

Comment: Eso me retorna el api

Comment: como quieres que quede tu chart?? la barras viene de aspectResult y los labels?

Comment: en la data va el aspectResult y en los labels aspectId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
let data = 
{
  "evaluationDetails":[
  { "aspectId": 1, "aspectResult": 100 },
  { "aspectId": 2, "aspectResult": 90 },
  { "aspectId": 3, "aspectResult": 10 },
  { "aspectId": 4, "aspectResult": 50 },
  { "aspectId": 5, "aspectResult": 40 }
  ], "evaluationTemplateId": 1, "entityId": 1, "result": 58
};


let aspectId=[];
let aspectResult=[];

for (let x in data["evaluationDetails"]) {
   aspectId.push(data["evaluationDetails"][x]["aspectId"]);
   aspectResult.push(data["evaluationDetails"][x]["aspectResult"]);
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: aspectId,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'resultados:',
        data: aspectResult,
        backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 5)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 5)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 5)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 5)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 5)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 5)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```